# Ubuntu installed on internal SATA harddisk vs. on external ssd: Which should yield better performance?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ssd, disk

I have Ubuntu installed on my workstation's internal HDD (SK hynix SC300B SATA 512GB). I am wondering if I will get a performance boost if I installed the OS on an external SSD (Samsung portable SS T7) and connect it to my workstation with USB 3.0.

Would there be a significant difference in read/write speeds? What other upsides/downsides should I expect from using Ubuntu on an external SSD?

Comment: You may be interested in this similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/978815/external-ssd-vs-internal-standard-hd-for-speed

Comment: Here this one is much better: https://superuser.com/a/1563079

Answer (score 1):

I believe you (in some cases) can get somewhat better performance, but not "through-the-roof" better.

I found some benchmarks on the [SK hynix disk you mentioned](https://www.harddrivebenchmark.net/hdd.php?hdd=SK+hynix+SC300B+512GB&id=13316) - as well as for the [Samsung disk](https://www.thessdreview.com/hardware/portable-ssds/samsung-t7-portable-2tb-ssd-review/2/).

It looks like the Samsung is slightly faster, but only by a small margin. Also, the USB 3.0 connection i probably going to be the limiting factor for an external SSD.

Keep in mind that performance will also very much depend on how the disk is utilized. Also, see [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/979365/1162847) for some important limitations when using a SSD over USB.